# Why Android VideoView is not playing WMV, but native video player does?

Tags: android, android-videoview, wmv

I am developing a Android app that plays advertising videos. All the videos are in WMV format and I tested it in Android 4.2 and it worked great. The client tried to execute the app it in a 4.1 device and it didn't work. It only says "Can't play this video" and crashes. We tried to play a WMV video with the native Video player in the 4.1 device and it played as expected. Why, in the same device, the VideoView can't play a video that the native Video player can? I also tried with another 4.1 device and a 4.1 emulator and I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the WMV is not supported before 4.2 you can refer to the official documentation of google 
http://developer.android.com

Comment: But how come the native video player, that came with the 4.1 device , plays the WMV video? Is it a special feature?

Comment: i think that this issue is implemented with NDK application.